# angular RouteReuseStrategy scroll position keep

Tags: angular, angular-router

angular RouteReuseStrategy scroll position error.

When I returned to the list page from another page, the scroll bar went back to the top

```
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle, RouteReuseStrategy} from '@angular/router';

export class SystemRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

  handlers: {[key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle} = {};

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    if (route.data.reuse) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path] = handle;
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    return this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path]; 
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
  }

}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions  you can set  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled', in your routerOptions

Comment: imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})],  is invalid

Comment: Unable to recover overflow attribute set on element, scroll position

Comment: also set this anchorScrolling: 'enabled',

Comment: scrollPositionRestoration supports scrollbar on window. But the div label scroll bar on overflow: Auto is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refer to ionic,

A new `<router-outlet>` named `<active-outlet>` is added.

It will not destroy the component, The component will be set to hidden.

And add a new life cycle function

```
ngOnChanges

ngOnInit <- first entry create component 

onReuse  <- second entry or router back reuse component 

ngDoCheck

ngAfterContentInit

ngAfterContentChecked

ngAfterViewInit

ngAfterViewChecked

onLeave   <- router level

ngOnDestroy  <-  Manual destroy trigger
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using the window scrolling but a div with auto overflow, you should subscribe to the router events and save the position.

Here is an example (I'm using [Angular Material Sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) as a container, but you can change to a general div)

```js
lastPosition: number
lastRoute: string
@ViewChild('grid') grid: MatDrawerContent // change to ElementRef or other type

constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((events) => events instanceof NavigationStart || events instanceof NavigationEnd)
  ).subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart && event.url !== this.lastRoute) {
      this.lastRoute = this.router.url
      this.lastPosition = this.grid.measureScrollOffset('top') // get the scrollTop property
      // this.lastPosition = this.grid.nativeElement.scrollTop
    } 
    else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url === this.lastRoute) {
      this.grid.scrollTo({ top: this.lastPosition }) // set scrollTop to last position
      // this.grid.nativeElement.firstChild.scrollTop  = this.lastPosition
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have rebuilt the router-outlet to solve this problem, but it will take up a lot of memory. Recommended reference ionic,  ion-router

Comment: Actually I am using window scrolling, and it works as well. In this case you need to store `window.scrollY` and when restoring the scroll position, you need to wrap the statement in requestAnimationFrame: `requestAnimationFrame(() => window.scrollTo({ top: this.lastPosition }));`

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much. I have rebuilt the router-outlet to solve this problem, but it will take up a lot of memory. Recommended reference ionic,  ion-router